# Adding option to dropdown list using jQuery odd behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two dropdown lists that get their options using jQuery. For the most part they work just fine. The only issue I'm having is that when I try to add an "All" option just one takes it.

```
$("#dropdown").prepend($('<option>', {value: '',text: 'Select Fiscal Year'})).attr("selected","selected").append($('<option>', {value: 'All',text: 'All'}));
$("#dropdownRO").prepend($('<option>', {value: '',text: 'Select RO'})).attr("selected","selected").append($('<option>', {value: 'All',text: 'All'}));
```

As you can see both are almost identical, but only one takes the ".append($('', {value: 'All',text: 'All'}))" at a time. If I remove from one then the other adds the option. I even tried:

```
 $("#dropdown").prepend($('<option>', {value: 'All',text: 'All'}));
 $("#dropdownRO").prepend($('<option>', {value: 'All',text: 'All'}));
```

And the same happens. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fkG3P/ can you show your HTML as well? it might be malformed.

Comment: Actually, I realized that the issue was that I was running this in the wrong place. I'm loading the rest of the options using jQuery SPServices, and I was adding the "All" option before SPServices ran. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the issue was that I was running this in the wrong place. This way will work:

```
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
listName: "{ListID}",
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Fiscal_x0020_Year' /><FieldRef Name='Regional_x0020_Office' /></ViewFields>",
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
        var dropDown = "<option value='" + $(this).attr("ows_Fiscal_x0020_Year") + "'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Fiscal_x0020_Year") + "</option>";
        var dropDownRO = "<option value='" + $(this).attr("ows_Regional_x0020_Office") + "'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Regional_x0020_Office") + "</option>";
        $("#dropdown").append(dropDown);
        $("#dropdownRO").append(dropDownRO);
    }); //end of each() function
    /////////////Deletes duplicates from dropdown list////////////////
    var usedNames = {};
    $("#dropdown > option, #dropdownRO > option").each(function () {
        if (usedNames[this.text]) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
        }
    });
    //Adds All and Select Options--------------
    $("#dropdown").append($('<option>', {
        value: 'All',
        text: 'All'
    })).prepend($('<option>', {
        value: '',
        text: 'Select Fiscal Year',
        select: 'selected'
    }));
    $("#dropdownRO").prepend($('<option>', {
        value: '',
        text: 'Select RO'
    })).attr("selected", "selected").append($('<option>', {
        value: 'All',
        text: 'All'
    }));
} //end of completeFunc
}); //end of SPServices
```